# Read and execute a file as a variable in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a file and its structure is like this:

```
({
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'foo'
})
```

I'm trying to load and read the file in `NodeJS` so that I can get the `object` as a variable; what's the best way to do this? **Note** that I can't change the file's structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the file into a string and `eval` that string:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var s = fs.readFileSync('myfile.js', 'utf8');
var x = eval(s);
```

If necessary, you could modify the string `s` before calling `eval`.

I have to agree with [mtsr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022776/read-and-execute-a-file-as-a-variable-in-nodejs/15027179#15027179) that a solution using `JSON.parse` is better (both in terms of security and probably performance as well). However, the current data file does not represent a JSON structure due to the extra parenthesis surrounding the object literal.

**if** you are certain that the object literal `{..}` is always surrounded by a `(..)` pair, you can remove them and then attempt to parse the string:

```
m = s.match(/\(([\s\S]+)\)/);
x = JSON.parse(m[1]);
```

The `[\s\S]+` part of the regexp, matches anything including newline characters. The `\(` and `\)` part matches the surrounding parenthesis.

Comment: Ah `eval`, I was hoping to avoid this since my coworkers would probably laugh, taunt and generally make jokes about me for the rest of the project!

Comment: Using eval is bad advice. Use JSON.parse() instead.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` cannot handle the extra parenthesis. Of course, if this is the problem, one could manually strip them from the string and then process the result through `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid eval. Try

```
JSON.parse()
```

instead.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work as when I do: `JSON.parse(({
     foo: 'bar',
     bar: 'foo'
 }))`, it reports an error :(

Comment: +1 for JSON.parse. Edited my answer to include that alternative along with the required removal of the extra parens.